# Extra "mystery" markup being printed to page

Tags: navigation, theming

I have a strange thing happening. If you see this page:

http://morningsidecenter-teachablemoment.org/teachable-moment

you will see a pretty much broken super fish nav (that until earlier tonight was working.) If you inspect the element you will find numerous empty `<a></a>` being printed to the page...

I went through and undid all the work i had done, but to no avail. Has anyone ever encountered this sort of thing? I've combed over my .tpl files to see if there is anything strange going on, but I cannot see anything (though it is late). Also, when I am logged in the error does not present itself, nor does it on interior pages for that section; click on any item in the sub menu, and you will see the nav is not broken, and no extra markup in the form of empty `<a></a>` tags...

thoroughly flummoxed...

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Please post screenshots instead of links, as otherwise the question will be useless to others once you've fixed your problem.

Comment: You should also show the markup you see for those empty tags, including the tags before, and after them. So far, I don't see any empty tags as described in the question. @Letharion is right, and without a screenshot, and a snippet showing the markup for those links, the question will be probably closed as too localized.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I did refresh the cache both from admin and user sides... no dice. Since i am a new user d.se.com wont allow me to post images. If you guys arent seeing anything extraordinarily broken as i am, that gives me a little hope. though its cold comfort...

Comment: Just add a link to a page showing the screenshot; one of the users with the right reputation will convert it in a screenshot. Anyway, this question is too localized, as forgetting to close a tag is like forgetting to (for example) close a string with its string delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I view source on the page you can see there is a unclosed anchor tag in this chunk:

```
<div class="view-footer">
      <a href="teachable-moment/lessons?field_area_tid=12&field_topic_tid=All&field_grade_level_tid=All">
<h4 class="TMlandingTitle">Posted in Classroom Ideas & Resources</h4>
<a/>    </div>
```

Is this a hard-coded chunk of html in a view? Looks like you have mixed around the closing `<a>`

Comment: It is some hard coded mark up in my view footer...
Faulty late night HTML was my problem! thanks to everyone who helped! always be validating!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the additional anchor tags (tested in Firefox and IE8 for windows), but there a bunch of other problems that might be causing oddities.

There's a div inside your head tags at line 89

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Basically, I'd recommend running your site through http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ and fixing as many of those issues as you can. Then see if your problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. proceeding as per your recommendation.